# How to return authorization error to jqgrid if Authorize and HandleJsonexception are used in DynamicGridData

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid, mono, asp.net-authorization

[HandleJsonException] and code from Oleg answer in
[ASP.NET MVC 2.0 Implementation of searching in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500805/asp-net-mvc-2-0-implementation-of-searching-in-jqgrid)

are used to show error to users in ASP.NET MVC2 applicaton.

DynamicGridData method is also decorated with [Authorize].
Page contains "log out" button.

If user logs off and presses back button in browser, [Authorize] causes ASP.NET returns logon page in html format as DynamicGridData  result.

jqgrid shows strange error in this case. How to return error in proper json format like [HandleJsonException] returns for other errors ?

unreadable aler box containing raw html appears.

ASP.NET code in referenced an